# Java Load balancing Tcp proxy server design

Tags: java, design-patterns, tcp, architecture, distributed

I want to design and implement a proxy server which accepts client requests and then reads host connection configurations from a property file and by using round robin algorithm selects available host and then passes client request to the selected host through creating a new socket between proxy server and host .My question is what should be the best practice and how to handle if available hosts are not reachable what should be the appropriate way. What is the most suitable design pattern that I should use

[image]

Comment: What design pattern? There's no decision to make. If you get an outbound connect error you have to try another host. If you've tried them all, you have to return an error to the downstream client.

Comment: @EJP In here between proxy server and hosts do we have create socket per request from proxy server side

Comment: Why are you creating a new socket between proxy and host? After the initial setup the client could directly connect to the host, to prevent the proxy from being bottle neck.

Comment: did you check haproxy?

Comment: @mike if we are not creating new client socket between proxy server and hosts per request there is a problem sending correct response to the client when it comes to concurrent users isn't it

Comment: @techuser yes i have checked it that works fine .but im trying to implement a own solution

Answer (score 2):

This is a traditional question for balancing load between host according to some pattern, You mentioned your intention is to use 'Round Robbin', But there are a lot of load balancing patterns you can use, [Apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) does provide most of the services, if you want to implement pure load balancing, try camel source code, but instead you can use stable camel implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this article actually explained in conceptual way of different loading balancing algorithms that could be implemented. [load balancing algorithms](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/intro-to-load-balancing-for-developers-ndash-the-algorithms)

Using simple round robin, if any host[i] is not available when trying to dispatch client's incoming request, just mark its status as unavailable.

1. And one strategy is to neglect unavailable hosts ever after.
2. Another option is to still check unavailable hosts upon next time in case it will become available again.
3. Another better active monitoring way could be done that periodic heartbeats will be sent between proxy server and hosts to determine the availability instead of at request dispatching time.

But which way to use really depends on your performance goal (e.g. throughput, latency), each host handling capabilities, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it with by creating client sockets per connection between proxy server and hosts because if not there's a problem sending correct response for the client request that is what i think in that situation what do u prefer to keep all connection sockets or to create client socket per request and thats how i implemented it so far plus when i try to connect from proxy server to host if host is not reachable it throws exception then i mark it as unavailable what is the most appropriate way